# wpf control width binding

Tags: wpf, binding, width

I have two borders with content, The second border width changes depending
on the content, I'm trying to bind the first border to the second border width but
it's not working and I'm not sure what i'm missing. Can someone give me some direction please?
Below is a example of what I'm currently trying.

```
<Border x:Name="border1" Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=border2}">
    ... 
</Border>

<Border x:Name="border2">
    ...
</Border>
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Change the path to `ActualWidth`.

```
<Border x:Name="border1" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=border2}">
</Border>
<Border x:Name="border2">
</Border>
```

Comment: Thanks. I looked up ActualWidth and found this link. http://stackoverflow.com/q/607827/684042    it makes sense to me now. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

change path to ViewportWidth too !

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
//and some elements exist there
  <Grid> 
    <Border x:Name="border_btn" Width="{Binding ElementName=root ,Path=ViewportWidth, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>  
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

use ViewportWidth instead of ActualWidth because in this case ActualWidth is always shown 0! 
for test this problem you can test this with this line in your xaml.

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding  ElementName=mainGrid, Path=ActualWidth ,Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="Red"/>
```

Comment: @Bart its an answer not a comment!

Comment: There's already an accepted answer on a 5 year old question, if you think your answer is better, it should be more descriptive than 5 words and explain why yours is better.