# Bind width of UI element to a percentage of another UI element's width

Tags: wpf, xaml

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873007/wpf-control-width-binding), but slightly different.

I'm not sure if this is possible. Is there any way to link an UI element's width to another element's width **percentage**?

For example:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollviewerWrapper">

     <TextBlock x:Name="textblock" 
                Width="{Binding Path=Width, [[[ % of ]]] ElementName=scrollviewerWrapper}" />

</ScrollViewer>
```

So if my ScrollViewer is 100px, I want my TextBlock to be 60% of that = 60px (the scrollviewer's width is dynamic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I ended up using a converter to pass a number. Only think, instead of a percentage I went for the remainder of the total minus a fixed width, because I had a number for that.

XAML:

```
Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=exampleElement, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource ResourceKey=actionAreaWidth}}">
```

Parameter conversion:

```
<clr:Double x:Key="actionAreaWidth">150</clr:Double>
```

And the converter itself:

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

            double percentage = 100;
            double.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out percentage);

            var actualWidth = (double)value;
            return actualWidth * (percentage / 100);
        }
```