# Visibility and height problems when using wpf usercontrol in winforms project

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, height

I have two related problems that occur in the following situation.

I have a winforms window that contains some panels. In a few of these panels there are a number of (custom) wpf user-controls.

## 1

if i check .Visible on the elementhost it always returns true. even though I can see that its not visible.

## 2

if i check .Height it will always give me the same size. even though the control itself shows a variable number of things and changes size acordingly (through Visibility.collaps);

how can I get to the correct values?

edit: code added

Okey Now I'm officialy going crazy.
If I add a few messageboxes in my code to check when and in what order the above code gets executed. When I do this everything works! but as soon as I delete the messageboxes it reverses the effect. Instead of getting bigger when needed it gets smaller en vice versa....
wtf wpf!

```
private Size bereken_panel(Panel P)
    {
        Size Sz = new Size();
        int tmp_H = 42;
        foreach (Control SC in P.Controls)
        {
            if (SC is SplitContainer)
            {
                if (SC.Visible)
                {
                    tmp_H += SC.Height;
                }
            }
            else if (SC is System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost)
            {
                if ((SC as System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost).Child.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
                {
                    tmp_H += (int)(SC as System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost).Child.RenderSize.Height;
                }
            }
        }
       // tmp_H = 42 + n_showed * 25;
        if (tmp_H < 65)
        {
            tmp_H = 65;
        }
        Sz.Height = tmp_H;
        Sz.Width = 432;
        return Sz;
    }
```

so this is after some extra modification
to clarify where the TopLeft point is.

```
 int p_x_links = panel1.Width / 2 - 436;
        int p_x_rechts = panel1.Width / 2 + 4;
        //links
        p_contact_gegevens.Size = bereken_panel(p_contact_gegevens);
        p_telnrs.Location = new Point(p_x_links, p_contact_gegevens.Size.Height + p_contact_gegevens.Location.Y + 8);
        p_telnrs.Size = bereken_panel(p_telnrs);
        p_bezoekadres.Location = new Point(p_x_links, p_telnrs.Size.Height + p_telnrs.Location.Y + 8);
        p_bezoekadres.Size = bereken_panel(p_bezoekadres);
        //rechts
        p_administratie.Size = bereken_panel(p_administratie);
        p_postadres.Location = new Point(p_x_rechts, p_administratie.Size.Height + p_administratie.Location.Y + 8);
        p_postadres.Size = bereken_panel(p_postadres);
```

Comment: Can you provide code parts, where you have problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Most probabbly the control is overlapped by some other control. Visibility property in this case can be even True.
2. Try to use [ActualWidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607827/what-is-the-difference-between-width-and-actualwidth-in-wpf) instead.

**EDIT**

Sorry, the example is on `ActualWidth`, but you are asking for `Height`. Concept is the same btw.

Comment: ActualHeight is the same as RenderSize.Height? and Height is the same desiredsize correct?

Comment: so no changes in height. but the controls are not overlapping but side to side

Comment: @Daanvl: Where is TopLeft point of the Panel (assuming that size is calculated correctly)?

Comment: @Daanvl: I still see use of Height in calculations, instead of ActualHeight. Try to user real redered size and see if it helps you.

Comment: I can only use that in wpf. the form is winforms so there is only the Height property and nothing else. When there's a wpf element I Use RenderdSize.Height. I don't understand where else I should be using ActualHeight(even the elementhost doesnt have ActualHeight)