# The height and width properties of the WPF window remain zero after running Storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window, wpf-controls

In order for my app's storyboard to work properly, I must divide the window's height and width by two and then use those values as the `CenterY` and `CenterX` values.

`XAML`:

```
<Window x:Name="GanjAsemanMainWindow" x:Class="Ganj_Aseman.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ganj_Aseman"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Loaded="GanjAsemanMainWindow_Loaded" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" FontSize="13" Height="535" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" Title="MainWindow" Width="764" WindowStyle="None">
    <Window.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform CenterX="{Binding}" CenterY="{Binding}" Angle="{Binding}"/>
    </Window.RenderTransform>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="WindowRotation">
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" SpeedRatio="2.5" Duration="00:00:2" From="{Binding Path=Height,ElementName=GanjAsemanMainWindow}" To="0" AutoReverse="False" Storyboard.TargetName="GanjAsemanMainWindow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"/>
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" SpeedRatio="2.5" Duration="00:00:2" From="{Binding Path=Width,ElementName=GanjAsemanMainWindow}" To="0" AutoReverse="False" Storyboard.TargetName="GanjAsemanMainWindow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"/>
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" SpeedRatio="3.5" Duration="00:00:2" From="0" To="360" AutoReverse="False" Storyboard.TargetName="GanjAsemanMainWindow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="MinimizeIconImage" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="MinimizeIconImage_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" MouseEnter="MinimizeIconImage_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="MinimizeIconImage_MouseLeave" GotFocus="MinimizeIconImage_GotFocus" LostFocus="MinimizeIconImage_LostFocus" Focusable="True" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Cursor="Hand" Height="47"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding}" Margin="0,2,67,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="52"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`C#`:

```
private void MinimizeIconImage_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //I checked the height and width values after resizing using "Grip" here
    RotateTransform RT = new RotateTransform(0, Width/2 ,Height/2);
    GanjAsemanMainWindow.RenderTransform = RT;
    (Resources["WindowRotation"] as Storyboard).Begin();
}
```

When the storyboard first runs and the height and width values become zero, I resize the window using the `Grip` icon, but the values of those two properties do not change and remain zero.

[image: Output]

Best regards,

Reza Jaferi

Comment: Have you checked the ``ActualWidth`` and the ``ActualHeight``?

Comment: As @AndrewKeepCoding mentioned, and note that these values are not assigned before OnLoaded or OnResized events, so try to call the Animation's Begin() method at the end of the Loaded event..

Comment: @RezaJaferi: What values do you expect to change and when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607827/what-is-the-difference-between-width-and-actualwidth-in-wpf), `Width`/`Height` is the requested size. In this case, we need to use `ActualWidth`/`ActualHeight`.

XAML:

```xml
From="{Binding Path=ActualHeight,ElementName=GanjAsemanMainWindow}"
From="{Binding Path=ActualWidth,ElementName=GanjAsemanMainWindow}"
```

C#:

```cs
RotateTransform RT = new RotateTransform(0, ActualWidth / 2, ActualHeight / 2);
```